# DOS ethernet driver

Tags: ethernet, ms-dos

I am trying to run Arachne software on my DOS boot USB. Arachne is fine but I need a DOS driver for my 802.11n Wireless LAN Card. I do not know much more information and am only 70% sure that is the right card. I am running DOS 6.22 If you need anymore informaion please ask.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to be using DOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web browser "Arachne" is also available for Linux.

The chance to get a tiny Linux working with your WiFi card with existing components and drivers is much higher than getting it done with DOS. MS-DOS did not even had an IP stack.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you'll be able to find NDIS driver support for **ANY** wifi adapter.  There simply isn't a driver-stack built for DOS that supports the necessary bits for WIFI.  Your best bet is to look towards a wired card and plugging that into an access-point in station mode.